# How can I automatically create list_filters for all my models in a django admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have a Django site, using admin to manage the models. Currently, I am using

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

for name, var in databuild_models.__dict__.items():
    if type(var) is ModelBase:
        admin.site.register(var)
```

To register all the models in the module with the admin module. However, I want to automatically add list_filters for every attribute on each model. I've read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/ where they use the form:

```
class MymodelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['model_name_attribute']
```

and then

```
admin.site.register(models.MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Is there a way to similarly loop through each attribute in a model, and add it to a filter list?

For example:

```
filter_list_fields = []
for attr in MyModel:
    filter_list_fields.append(str(attr))
list_filter = filter_list_fields
```

and then register them as a general class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can use the [applications api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#module-django.apps) to get a list of models in your app, rather than inspecting the module's `__dict__`

In Django 1.8+, you can get a list of field names for a model using [`Model._meta.get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields) method. I've excluded the automatically generated `id` field, and you might find you want to make further improvements.

In python, you can create a class dynamically using [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type). You need the name of the new class (not important here), the base classes that it inherits from (in this case `Admin.ModelAdmin`, and a dictionary of attributes (in this case, there is only one attribute, `list_filter`).

Finally, register the model with the custom model admin we have created.

Putting it together, your admin.py should look something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.apps import apps

app_config  = apps.get_app_config('myapp')
models = app_config.get_models()

for Model in models:
    fieldnames = [f.name for f in Model._meta.get_fields() if f.name != 'id']
    ModelAdmin = type('ModelAdmin', (admin.ModelAdmin,), {'list_filter': fieldnames})
    admin.site.register(Model, ModelAdmin)
```